# Reading ints from standard input and saving them - C

Tags: c, input, scanf

The ﬁrst line of input contains one integer. Each input is then followed by a line containing two integers, each no larger than 1 000 000. The ﬁrst integer n is the size of the vector and the second integer m is the number of lines register information from. Each of the following lines contains two integers x and y indicating that. Any two integers in a line are separated by one white space. The lines contain no othercharacters, aside from the ﬁnishing new line

so I chose the x as the position in the vector. x is stored in `num1` in the `my_struct` structure and y is stored in `num2`

```
typedef struct my_struct{
  int num1;
  int num2;
  bool my_bool;
} my_struct;


int main(){
   int testCase, sizeVector, numLines, num1_in, num2_in, linesScanned = 0;
   scanf("%d\n %d %d", &testCase, &sizeVector, &numLines);

   my_struct my_vector[sizeVector+1];

   my_vector[0].num1 = testCase;
   my_vector[0].num2 = 0;
   my_vector[0].my_bool = false;

   while (linesScanned < numLines) {
      scanf("%d %d\n ", &num1_in, &num2_in);
      my_vector[num1].num1 = num1_in;
      my_vector[num1].num2 = num2_in;
      my_vector[num1].my_bool = false;
      linesScanned++;

   }}
```

input example:

```
1
3 2
1 2
2 3
```

my problem is that the first `scanf` works well, but the on on the loop doesn't. It doesn't save the values as it should

Comment: what is `num1` (the one you're using as an index for `my_vector`)?

Comment: yes, that's what I was using it for.

Comment: I mean, you do not increment it, do you? in the code you showed it is not clear whether or not it is updated on each iteration. So, it looks like you overwrite `my_vector`'s specific item on each iteration.

Comment: well I was kind of hoping it would be the value that was coming from the `scanf` - I see now where I made my mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the second `scanf()`:

```
scanf("%d %d\n ", &num1_in, &num2_in);
```

by

```
scanf(" %d %d", &num1_in, &num2_in);
```

In fact in your second `scanf()` you do not catch the new line before starting reading integers. The new line is entered in your input but it is not catched neither in the first `scanf()` nor in your second `scanf()`

Adding space at the beginning of the string format in your second `scanf()` will catch any white space (spaces, tabulation , new lines...)

Comment: That's not how `scanf` works, but it doesn't matter in this particular input.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to get rid of the `\n` in your `scanf` functions. In fact you can get rid of the spaces too. When using `%d` all whitespace in the input is ignored.

You also don't appear to be incrementing your array index.

Answer (score 1):

Your second `scanf` should be:

```
scanf(" %d %d", &num1_in, &num2_in);
```